# Is there a way to check for a new-page action occurrence in a PeopleSoft SQR?

Tags: report, peoplesoft, sqr

I'm wondering if there is a way that when the SQR automatically reaches the last line and calls the page break, if there is a global variable or procedure associated with a new-page function that can be checked?
Problem:
I'm printing a report and although I personally can manage a new-page, setting a $First_Row = 'Y' to control where the first row prints, when the program does it automatically when a data set overflows to the next page, this variable is not tripped, causing a different print position to be called. How do I check without a line counter?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the #current-line reserved variable can be used to see page endings. This then resets when the new page is called so I can use this to check for the new first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a procedure to execute using "Use-Procedure"

For example:

```
Use-Procedure
    Before-Page=DoThisProcAfterNewPage
    After-Page=DoThisProcBeforeNewPage
```

Yes, they seem backwards.